# How can I scale tikz picture to full width?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In my original version, the picture was sacaled nicely to the full width of the page. Unfortunatelly, I don't have a screenshot of that. Then I increased radius to 5 (everything fine), decreased it again, an now the picture is too small:

[image]

Any hint?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\textsf{x}}
\rhead{\textsf{x}}
\lfoot{\textsf{\tiny x \LaTeX \ | \today}}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} 

\begin{document}

$\blacksquare$ \textbf{x}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex][transform canvas={scale=2.0}]
% Draw the lines at multiples of pi/6
\foreach \ang in {0,...,11} {
  \draw [lightgray] (0,0) -- (\ang*360/12:2.5);
}

% Draw the lines at multiples of pi/4
\foreach \ang in {0,...,7} {
  \draw [lightgray] (0,0) -- (\ang*360/8:2.5);
}

% Concentric circles and radius labels
\foreach \s in {0, 1, 2} {
  \draw [lightgray] (0,0) circle (\s + 0.5);
  \draw (0,0) circle (\s);
  \node [fill=white] at (\s, 0) [below] {\scriptsize $\s$};
}

% Add the labels at multiples of pi/4
\foreach \ang/\lab/\dir in {
  0 /0       /right,
  1 /{\pi/4} /{above right},
  2 /{\pi/2} /above,
  3 /{3\pi/4}/{above left},
  4 /{\pi}   /left,
  5 /{5\pi/4}/{below left},
  7 /{7\pi/4}/{below right},
  6 /{3\pi/2}/below} {
    \node [fill=white] at (\ang*360/8:2.6) [\dir] {\scriptsize $\lab$};
}
% The double-lined circle around the whole diagram
\draw [style=double] (0,0) circle (2.5);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Example from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169624/creating-a-polar-grid-with-tikz). Related questions [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54091/tikzs-picture-scaled-and-wrapped) and [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29142/automagically-scale-tikz-picture-and-use-externalization) didn't solve the problem or I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea taken from [this very nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6391/156344).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\textsf{x}}
\rhead{\textsf{x}}
\lfoot{\textsf{\tiny x \LaTeX \ | \today}}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} 
\makeatletter
\usepackage{environ}
\newsavebox{\measure@tikzpicture}
\NewEnviron{scaletikzpicturetowidth}[1]{%
  \def\tikz@width{#1}%
  \def\tikzscale{1}\begin{lrbox}{\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \BODY
  \end{lrbox}%
  \pgfmathparse{#1/\wd\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \edef\tikzscale{\pgfmathresult}%
  \BODY
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{scaletikzpicturetowidth}{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\tikzscale,>=latex]
\foreach \ang in {0,...,11} {
  \draw [lightgray] (0,0) -- (\ang*360/12:2.5);
}

% Draw the lines at multiples of pi/4
\foreach \ang in {0,...,7} {
  \draw [lightgray] (0,0) -- (\ang*360/8:2.5);
}

% Concentric circles and radius labels
\foreach \s in {0, 1, 2} {
  \draw [lightgray] (0,0) circle (\s + 0.5);
  \draw (0,0) circle (\s);
  \node [fill=white] at (\s, 0) [below] {\scriptsize $\s$};
}

% Add the labels at multiples of pi/4
\foreach \ang/\lab/\dir in {
  0 /0       /right,
  1 /{\pi/4} /{above right},
  2 /{\pi/2} /above,
  3 /{3\pi/4}/{above left},
  4 /{\pi}   /left,
  5 /{5\pi/4}/{below left},
  7 /{7\pi/4}/{below right},
  6 /{3\pi/2}/below} {
    \node [fill=white] at (\ang*360/8:2.6) [\dir] {\scriptsize $\lab$};
}
% The double-lined circle around the whole diagram
\draw [style=double] (0,0) circle (2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{scaletikzpicturetowidth}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you understand, why it worked in a first place? Really a pitty, that it changed ;-)

Comment: @Christoph What do you mean by "first place" and "it changed"?

Comment: As I tried to explain: It scaled nicely, but after increasing - decreasing the radius, the scaling didn't work anymore. (The fist picture I had looked similar to yours!).

Comment: @Christoph Could you add your (not working) code to your question? I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Strange, the code in my example above still reproduces the picture. I just tried it again with the same result! The width is less than half the available space...